# How can I calculate the expected number of changes of state of a discrete-time Markov chain?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Assume we have a 2 state Markov chain with the transition matrix:
$$
\left[
\begin{array}
(p & 1-p\\
1-q & q
\end{array}
\right]
$$
and we assume that the first state is the starting state. What is the expected number of state transitions in $T$ periods? (I want to count the number of state changes from state 1 to state 2, and the other way round).

Comment: Have you tried using a geometric random variable approach?

Comment: @GautamShenoy, what is a geometric random variable approach?

Comment: If you toss a coin which gives heads with probability p, repeatedly till the first tail arrives, the number of tosses is a geometric random variable. I thought this problem could be modeled using this idea but since you have a limit on the number of steps i.e. $T$, I don't think it will work. I'll get back to you on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Let $s=(2-p-q)^{-1}$, then $\pi_0=(1-q)s$, $\pi_1=(1-p)s$, defines a stationary distribution $\pi$. If the initial distribution is $\pi$, at each step the distribution is $\pi$ hence the probability that a jump occurs is
$$
r=(1-p)\pi_0+(1-q)\pi_1=2(1-p)(1-q)s.
$$
In particular, the mean number of jumps during $T$ periods is exactly $rT$.

**2.** By a coupling argument, for any distribution $\nu$, the difference between the number of jumps of the Markov chain with initial distribution $\nu$ and the number of jumps of the Markov chain with initial distribution $\pi$ is exponentially integrable.

**3.** Hence, for any starting distribution, the mean number of jumps during $T$ periods is $rT+O(1)$.

**4.** Note that
$$
\frac1r=\frac12\left(\frac1{1-p}+\frac1{1-q}\right),
$$
and that $\frac1{1-p}$ and $\frac1{1-q}$ are the mean lengths of the intervals during which the chain stays at $0$ and $1$ before a transition occurs to $1$ and $0$ respectively. Hence the formula. For a Markov chain with $n$ states and transition matrix $Q$, one would get
$$
\frac1r=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1-Q_{kk}}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $n_{i,T}$, $i=1,2$, the expected number of transitions in $T$ periods when starting from state $i$. You can set up the recursions
$$
n_{1,T} = p\, n_{1,T-1}+(1-p)(1+\,n_{2,T-1}),\quad n_{2,T} =q\, n_{2,T-1}+(1-q)(1+\,n_{1,T-1})
$$
with the obvious initial condition $n_{1,1}=1-p$ and $n_{2,1}=1-q$.

In matrix notation, this becomes
$$
\mathbf{n}_T = \mathbf{1}+\mathbf{M}\mathbf{n}_{T-1},
$$
where $\mathbf{n}_T=(n_{1,T},n_{2,T})^T$, $\mathbf{1}=(1-p,1-q)^T$, and $\mathbf{M}$ is your transition matrix.

Can you solve this recursion?